# react native, json response from POST. JSON unexpected EOF

Tags: json, react-native

If I do this in PostMan, I get a response back which I can toggle html and json, but in my react native app I'm getting a console error of `JSON Parse Error: Unexpected EOF`

I have the content type of my sent header as x-www-form-urlencoded because that was the only way to get my proper response even on postman.

I have my backend in wordpress sending a response array as json_encoded (`echo json_encode($response)`) and I can get it by url and post man, but my app just can't get past this unexpected EOF and I think it has to do with my `.then` statements

WHat am I doing wrong here?

```
validate(){
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;

    this.setState({ validating: true });

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('type', 'login');
    formData.append('email', this.state.email);
    formData.append('password', this.state.password);

    return fetch('https:/site/authentication.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => { 
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        })
      .catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
      })
}
```

Comment: Have you checked what the response that is that is coming back on this line of code? `.then(response => response.json())` after it converts it to JSON? usually if it's not valid JSON then that throws an error.

Comment: @amir5000 I've used console.log inside there instead of that, but what would be the best way to check?

Comment: @Amir5000 if I do this ```.then(response => {
    response.json();
    console.log(response.json());
   })``` then I get ```Promis {"_40: 0, "_55: null, _65: 0, _72: null} undefined```

Comment: Yeah a `console.log` is helpful before and after so like this: 
`.then(response => {

    console.log(response);

    const res = response.json();

    console.log(res);
    return res;
})`

Comment: @Amir5000 ```Response {
  "_bodyBlob": Blob {
    "_data": Object {
      "blobId": "31418cda-5d2e-4ee0-8c67-626e7ebe0502",
      "offset": 0,
      "size": 0,
    },
  },
  "headers": Headers {
    "map": Object {
      "cache-control": "public, max-age=0",
      "content-length": "0",
      "content-type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
    },
  },
  "ok": true,
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": undefined,
  "type": "default",
  "url": "https://site/authentication.php",
}
Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your response:

```
Response { "_bodyBlob": Blob { "_data": Object { "blobId": "31418cda-5d2e-4ee0-8c67-626e7ebe0502", "offset": 0, "size": 0, }, }, "headers": Headers { "map": Object { "cache-control": "public, max-age=0", "content-length": "0", "content-type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8", }, }, "ok": true, "status": 200, "statusText": undefined, "type": "default", "url": "https://site/authentication.php", } Promise { "_40": 0, "_55": null, "_65": 0, "_72": null, }
```

I think it is a blob not JSON. Try and use this instead:
`.then(response => response.blob())`

Sorry I missed that earlier.

Blob MDN Ref: [response.blob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob)

Comment: ok so I"m doing this now on my wordpress site (authentication.php) ```$response['status'] = true;
    $response['data'] = array(
     'auth_token'  => $token,
     'user_id'  => $user->ID,
     'user_login' => $user->user_login
    );
    $response['msg'] = 'Successfully Authenticated';
    
    echo json_encode($response);```
What else would I need to do?

Comment: See your response is `Successfully Authenticated` that is what will get sent back as text so you can handle this on the front end with the `response.text()` and that will work just fine.

Comment: Wait, what I just posted is in my php file on the site. But using Response.text isn't changing m my console

Comment: What do this log now? using .text() `.then(response => { const res = response.text(); console.log(res); return res; })`

Comment: It's the same as I posted before still

Comment: OK I missed that it is a blob, so I updated my answer.

Comment: ok that got me a bit closer but still doesn't have the data from my wordpress site, which comes through on PostMan. Do I need to add an await?

Comment: No hard to tell. what does this code log? `.then(data => { 
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        })` what is data after the blob()?

Comment: The bit with 40 55 65 72